# Django - Verify AWS Cognito token is valid before processing endpoint request

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I have this code below for checking a AWS Cognito token. I obviously don't want to add these 6 lines of code to every endpoint. Also I don't know if this is the proper way of validating all I'm doing is expecting the token to be of format ' ', parsing it and just decoding the JWT token part. How can I authenticate the AWS amplify token that comes with every request to ensure the user is properly logged in. I'd like to add this authentication to APIView endpoints and DRF api_view decorated endpoints.

views.py

```
import django.db.utils
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions, status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import *
from .models import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import JsonResponse
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi
from .core.api import jwt
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # 'Bearer z324weroko2iorjqoi=+3r3+3ij.2o2ij4='
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ')[1]
        print(token)
    
        # TODO this should be separated out to a login module
        try:
            res = jwt.decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            return Response(status=status.Http_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response("Invalid JWT", status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

@api_view(['GET'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="Get Goals joined by User"
)
def get_goals_by_user(request, user_id):
    try:
        # Get goal ids of user with id
        goals_query = JoinGoal.objects.filter(
            joiner_id=user_id).values_list('goal_id', flat=True)
        goals_list = list(goals_query)
        # Get Goals using list of goals PK with descriptions and uuid
        data = list(Goal.objects.filter(
            pk__in=goals_list).values('description', 'uuid'))
        response_data = dict(goals=data)
        return JsonResponse(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except JoinGoal.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(dict(error=does_not_exist_msg(JoinGoal.__name__, 'joiner_id', user_id)), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `djangorestframework`, the answer from @bdbd would be your best option. Otherwise, you might want to explore the following options:

1. Implement your own decorator that will perform the authentication. This has the same idea as the [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator or the [@user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator. When writing such decorator for class-based views, you maybe interested with [django.utils.decorators.method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

```
from functools import partial, wraps

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


def cognito_authenticator(view_func=None):
    if view_func is None:
        return partial(cognito_authenticator)

    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check the cognito token from the request.
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ')[1]

        try:
            res = jwt.decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            # Authenticate res if valid. Raise exception if not.
        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You are forbidden here!")
        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped_view


# We can decorate it here before the class definition but can also be done before the class method itself. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class
@method_decorator(
    name="post",
    decorator=[
        cognito_authenticator,
    ],
)
class SomeView(View):
    @method_decorator(cognito_authenticator)  # As explained above, this is another way of putting the decorator
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Allowed entry!")

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Allowed entry!")


# Or if using function-based views
@api_view(['POST'])
@cognito_authenticator
def some_view(request):
    return HttpResponse(f"Allowed entry!")
```

2. Write a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware). Be aware that the [order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering) matters. Same idea as the default [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) which populates the `request.user` field. In your case, implement the `__call__` method where you would check the Cognito tokens. Do not proceed to the view when the token is invalid by returning e.g. `HttpResponseForbidden` as in this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356067/11043825).

```
class CognitoAuthenticatorMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ')[1]

        try:
            res = jwt.decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            # Authenticate res if valid. Raise exception if not.
        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return HttpResponseForbidden("You are forbidden here!")

        # Proceed if valid
        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'path.to.CognitoAuthenticatorMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

---

### Update

Here is a sample run using Option-1. For simplicity, `settings.py` is just the default settings.

**views.py**

```
from functools import partial, wraps

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import View  # If using django views
from rest_framework.views import APIView  # If using djangorestframework views


def cognito_authenticator(view_func=None):
    if view_func is None:
        return partial(cognito_authenticator)

    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # To simplify the authentication, we would check if there is a query parameter "name=me". If none, it is forbidden.
        if request.GET.get('name') == "me":
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseForbidden("You are forbidden here!")

    return wrapped_view


@method_decorator(  # Try this style-1
    name="get",
    decorator=[
        cognito_authenticator,
    ],
)
class SomeView(View):  # If using djangorestframework view, this can also inherit from APIView or others e.g. class SomeView(APIView):
    @method_decorator(cognito_authenticator)  # Or try this style-2
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse(f"Allowed entry!")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from my_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("some-view/", views.SomeView.as_view()),
]
```

**Sample run:**

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/some-view/?name=notme
You are forbidden here!
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/some-view/?name=me
Allowed entry!
```

Comment: what should "name" be in model_decorator be if it's on an APIView with multiple endpoint requests: GET, POST, PUT?

Comment: It's the name of the class method that you want to decorate, such as "post", "get", "put", etc. See how it's used [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). As you can see in that reference, you can also just put it directly on the method instead of the class.

Comment: I keep getting 'TypeError: cognito_authenticator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view_func'' error when I try to use it as described

Comment: I updated the answer, could you check if it works now?

Comment: rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'authenticate'

Comment: if you could help me get this working properly I'll give you the accepted answer

Comment: Just as a side note - your example code does not really validate the token. It just decodes it. Whether it's valid or not is a different story. Since Cognito is an OIDC provider, have a look how Auth0 is handling JWT token validation: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization#create-the-jwt-validation-decorator (it's OIDC as well). Instead of `AUTH0_DOMAIN` you will have your Cognito's hoster UI domain.

Comment: @user8714896 I updated my answer with a sample run of minimum configuration. You might be interested building on top of it and see what part you would have an error. Also, thank you AleksanderWons for the feedback, I clarified in my example code that further authentication must be performed.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano is there a way to add it to api_view decorator endpoint? On the endpoint with api_view decorator in my original post I get 'TypeError: wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request''

Comment: @user8714896 I updated my answer to include how you would do it on function-based views. In summary, replace `@method_decorator(cognito_authenticator)` to just `@cognito_authenticator`. I tried it and it worked on my side.

Comment: why do you have to use `@cognito_authenticator` over `@method_decorator?` What are the differences?

Comment: Because `method_decorator`, from the name itself specifically the `"method"` part, implies that it must be used for classes, this is also as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). If you are not using class-based views, then don't use it, just use the target decorator directly (here is `cognito_authenticator`).

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I have to wait 2 minutes but after that you'll get the bounty

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are using [**`DRF`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you can create your own authentication class and apply the processing of the JWT there:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework import exceptions


class MyCustomJWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ')[1]
        try:
            jwt.decode_cognito_jwt(token)
        except Exception:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid JWT')

        return AnonymousUser(), None


class MyCustomAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (MyCustomJWTAuthentication, )
```

Or if you want to apply it to all `APIView`s:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'path.to.MyCustomJWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Note that once the JWT decode fails, no other authentication classes will be checked. If you don't want this, change the handling for the `except` clause to not raise `AuthenticationFailed`.

Comment: would you say the way I am authenticating the token is the "proper way" to do it? At least with Cognito?

Comment: IMO it depends on how the token is used. The purpose of authentication is to identify a user, but if you just need a token that acts like a simple api key, then it should be fine.

Comment: if I do need to identify user such as get their email or username can I get that from the token?

Comment: is it possible to apply to all endpoints even DRF ones and have an blacklist of ones not to add it to?

Comment: `if I do need to identify user such as get their email or username can I get that from the token?` -- yes but it depends on how the jwt token was setup. If you decode it and find an email or some sort of id to identify a user then you can definitely use that

Comment: `is it possible to apply to all endpoints even DRF ones and have an blacklist of ones not to add it to?` -- I assume you mean *non-DRF* ones. Yes you can, in that case the answer of @Niel Godfrey Ponciano can work.

Comment: does your method only work on APIView? Not on DRF endpoints like the get_goals_by_users function in my original post? Looks like that authentication_classes variable needs to be put inside a class.

Comment: Yep since you used the `@api_view` decorator in `get_goals_by_users`, it will read the rest framework settings

Comment: If you want to set authentication classes explicitly in a function-based view, you use `@authentication_classes([<auth_class>])` decorator like shown [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme)

Comment: apparently api_view extends view which doesn't have a request instance (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/). Part of authenticating I think is that it requires it to be a request instance?

Comment: I think I need request instance, because all the AWS cognito information is added to that.