# Django - Add authenticator to every endpoint automatically unless otherwise specified

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I have this custom authenticator created and I have over 30 endpoints. For all, but 3 endpoints it requires authentication. So I'm pretty much adding `@custom_authenticator` to every function or `@method_decorator(custom_authenticator)` in the case of `APIView` classes. Is there a way I can automatically add this to endpoints and add a decorator that turns off authentication for specific endpoint functions? For example

```
@donotauth
def endpoint(request)
```

then `endpoint()` won't run the authenticator first. The solution should ideally work with the custom authenticator below

custom authenticator

```
def cognito_authenticator(view_func=None):
    if view_func is None:
        return partial(cognito_authenticator)

    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check the cognito token from the request.
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not auth:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header expected'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        parts = auth.split()

        if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must start with bearer'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) == 1:
            return Response(dict(error='Token not found'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) > 2:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must be Bearer token'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        token = parts[1]
        try:
            res = decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            expiration = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res['exp'])
            current_utc = datetime.utcnow()

            if current_utc > expiration:
                return Response(dict(error=f'current time:{current_utc} is after expiration:{expiration}',
                                     user_msg='Please login again'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return Response(dict(error="Invalid JWT"),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)  # Or HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped_view
```

**Solution 1 using Middleware:**

I tried adding middleware, but it throws an error for anything with `@api_view` decorator on it. The error I get is `AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response.` How do I setup my custom authentication on every endpoint regardless of if it has `@api_view` decorator or is `APIView`. The end goal should be to automatically add the above `cognito_authenticator` to any endpoint and a way to specify when not to use the authenticator (probably a functiond decorator)

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_description="Get <count> most recent posts by category"
)
def get_most_recent_posts_by_category(request, category, count):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Middleware

```
from datetime import datetime

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from cheers.core.api.jwt_helpers import decode_cognito_jwt


class CognitoMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not auth:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header expected'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        parts = auth.split()

        if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must start with bearer'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) == 1:
            return Response(dict(error='Token not found'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) > 2:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must be Bearer token'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        token = parts[1]
        try:
            res = decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            expiration = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res['exp'])
            current_utc = datetime.utcnow()

            if current_utc > expiration:
                return Response(dict(error=f'current time:{current_utc} is after expiration:{expiration}',
                                     user_msg='Please login again'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return Response(dict(error="Invalid JWT"),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)  # Or HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return None
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cheers.middleware.CognitoMiddleware.CognitoMiddleware'
]
```

**Solution 2 using authenticator**

authenticator.py

```
class CognitoAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not auth:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header expected'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        parts = auth.split()

        if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must start with bearer'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) == 1:
            return Response(dict(error='Token not found'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(parts) > 2:
            return Response(dict(error='Authorization header must be Bearer token'),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        token = parts[1]
        try:
            res = decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            expiration = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res['exp'])
            current_utc = datetime.utcnow()

            if current_utc > expiration:
                return Response(dict(error=f'current time:{current_utc} is after expiration:{expiration}',
                                     user_msg='Please login again'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return Response(dict(error="Invalid JWT"),
                            status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)  # Or HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return AnonymousUser(), None
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'cheers.utils.authenticator.CognitoAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

but on an `APIView` post function it gives the error `django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.`

Comment: That would be a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION 1 (DRF Custom Authentication classes approach)

I've already answered your similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007940/6759844) which uses the DRF authentication class approach. That approach will apply your authentication to all `APIView`s by default, and you can also specify which views don't need to use that authentication. This I think should solve all your your problems here.

If you decide on the DRF authentication class approach, you can disable authentication on a view by setting the `authentication_classes` to blank on a function-based view like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes


@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def view(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello for today! See you tomorrow!"})
```

For class-based views:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
```

Similar thing for `permission_classes`. The above example effectively means there is no security on the views! So don't forget to add the authentication and permission classes you want, for example:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([BasicAuthentication, ])
def view(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello for today! See you tomorrow!"})


class SomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, )
```

---

#### SOLUTION 2 (MIDDLEWARE)

But if you really want to use a middleware, I would suggest to just use [**`JsonResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) instead of DRF's `Response`. This is because `Response`'s `.accepted_renderer` is processed by the DRF's `APIView` class or DRF's `@api_view` decorator.

Since your middleware does not do that processing, you get the error. You might be tempted to move/use that processing to your middleware, but it is unnecessary IMO.

So your middleware can be:

```
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import JsonResponse

from cheers.core.api.jwt_helpers import decode_cognito_jwt


class CognitoMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not auth:
            return JsonResponse(dict(error='Authorization header expected'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        parts = auth.split()

        if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
            return JsonResponse(
                dict(error='Authorization header must start with bearer'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
            )

        elif len(parts) == 1:
            return JsonResponse(dict(error='Token not found'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        elif len(parts) > 2:
            return JsonResponse(
                dict(error='Authorization header must be Bearer token'), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
            )

        token = parts[1]

        try:
            res = decode_cognito_jwt(token)
            expiration = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res['exp'])
            current_utc = datetime.utcnow()

            if current_utc > expiration:
                return JsonResponse(
                    dict(error=f'current time:{current_utc} is after expiration:{expiration}',
                    user_msg='Please login again'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )

        except Exception:
            # Fail if invalid
            return JsonResponse(
                dict(error="Invalid JWT"),
                status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
            )  # Or HttpResponseForbidden()

        else:
            # Proceed with the view if valid
            return None
```

If you want to specify which views/urls you want this middleware to ignore, some things you can do:

1. Specify a separate reference for this middleware to use, for example a setting that lists urls that this middleware will ignore
2. Add some sort of flag to your view for this middleware to check whether to ignore a view or not

**EDIT:**

With regards to the 403 being returned on the DRF approach, it's explained [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses). One way to ensure 401 is returned is by returning `Bearer` in `authenticate_header()` like this:

```
class MyCustomAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        ...
    
    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'Bearer'
```

Answer (score 2):

**To add different level authentication in DRF API endpoint, You can use project level authentication coupled with view level authentication :**

```
# config/settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny', to allow all
    # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser', only admin
    # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly', only authenticated can write
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

# app_name/views.py
@permission_classes((IsAdminUser, ))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

In this case all endpoints are protected by the `IsAuthenticated` permission.
But the view `example_view` override the global permission and use `IsAdminUser` instead.